# How can I create private posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, posts

I need Authors to be able to create private posts for specific users. 
For example:
 **Author A** creates a post and assigns it to **User U**, so non-logged visitors and others users shouldn't be able to see that post because it's just for **User U**

Well I downloaded a plugin named **Specific user content** which doesnt let you see the content of the post but the problem is that you can still know about it's existance and even read its title on any wordpress grid.

Any ideas? :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) will help you.